# Realm object property with getter/setter always return first stored value

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a realm object:

```
class RMovements: Object {
    dynamic var name: String!
    dynamic var _quantity: Double = 0
    var quantity: Double {
        get {
            return _quantity / 1000
        }
        set {
            _quantity = newValue * 1000
        }
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "name"
    }
}
```

After creating this object in realm store

```
do {
    try realm.write({
        let m = RMovements()
        m.name = "john"
        m.quantity = 2
        realm.add(m, update: true)
    })
} catch _ {}
```

In result I got

```
RMovements {
    name = john;
    _quantity = 2000;
    quantity = 2;
}
```

Looks good! But now I want to change quantity to 9

```
do {
    try realm.write({
        let m = realm.objects(RMovements).filter("name=%@", "john").last!
        m.quantity = 9
        realm.add(m, update: true)
    })
} catch _ {}
```

And here is surprise

```
RMovements {
    name = john;
    _quantity = 9000;
    quantity = 2;
}
```

_quantity changed to 9000 properly, but quantity is still 2.
Why quantity still 2? It will always return first stored value and I don't understand why. Please help.

Demo project available on [GitHub](https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/RealmQuantityGetterBug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is that the `quantity` property isn't included in `ignoredProperties()` to let Realm know not to persist it, but it also isn't marked `dynamic`, which enables Realm to manage the property.

So it's in this in-between state that isn't supported. I suggest you mark the property as ignored:

```
class RMovements: Object {
    dynamic var name: String!
    dynamic var _quantity: Double = 0
    var quantity: Double {
        get {
            return _quantity / 1000
        }
        set {
            _quantity = newValue * 1000
        }
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "name"
    }

    override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["quantity"]
    }
}
```

Note that `Object`'s default `description` doesn't include ignored properties, so to print it, you'll need to override that:

```
override var description: String {
    return "RMovements {\n    name = \(name);\n    _quantity = \(_quantity);\n    quantity = \(quantity);\n}"
}
```

Then if I run your sample, I'll get the following log:

```
created
check: RMovements {
    name = john;
    _quantity = 2000.0;
    quantity = 2.0;
}
before update: RMovements {
    name = john;
    _quantity = 2000.0;
    quantity = 2.0;
}
after update: RMovements {
    name = john;
    _quantity = 9000.0;
    quantity = 9.0;
}
check: RMovements {
    name = john;
    _quantity = 9000.0;
    quantity = 9.0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Do I need to do something in migration block after adding ignoredProperties()?

Comment: If the property was previously managed, and you've removed it, yes. Removing a property from a Realm model is considered a schema-breaking change that requires you to bump the schema version: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#migrations

Comment: But it is bad solution.. because now I can't do anything with quantity property..

Comment: Why realm can't just store actual value of this property instead of only first stored value?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "can't do anything with quantity property". If it's ignored, you can continue to override its setter and getter. I also don't understand what you mean by "storing actual value" of the property. It's a computed property, with a custom setter and getter. You obviously don't _want_ to persist this property, only to compute it. Marking it as ignored allows you to do all that.